# understanding the use of the "_.[method call?] syntax in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have been using Leaflet as of late and enjoy the "lightness" of this API vs. OpenLayers. One of the things I am doing is looking at examples and/or source code from pages that use this API. I recently came across some code that I am at a complete loss as to the method it is using to call a method. There are several places where calls are made using `_.[method name]`, but I have no idea what the underscore is referring to. Ex. `_.sortBy(flights, function (value)`. Is this just creating a new function?? I'm used to the $ used for `jQuery`, but this underscore is new to me and I cannot find anything on the web about this. Can anyone help?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree and this code has nothing to do with leaflet??

A code block is included for reference.

```
map = L.map('map').setView([44.715514, -112.148438], 4);

// Add the Stamen toner tiles as a base layer
var baseLayer = new L.StamenTileLayer('toner', {
    detectRetina: true
}).addTo(map);

// Add a layer control
var layerControl = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

// Add a legend control
var legendControl = L.control.legend({
    autoAdd: false
}).addTo(map);

// Create a lookup of airports by code.  NOTE:  this is easy, but non-optimal, particularly with a large dataset
// Ideally, the lookup would have already been created on the server or created and imported directly
var airportsLookup = L.GeometryUtils.arrayToMap(airports, 'code');

// Sort flight data in descending order by the number of flights.  This will ensure that thicker lines get displayed
// below thinner lines
flights = _.sortBy(flights, function (value) {
    return -1 * value.cnt;
});

// Group flight data by airline code
var airlineLookup = _.groupBy(flights, function (value) {
    return value.airline;
});

var maxCountAll = Number(flights[0].cnt);

// Get the top count of flights
flights = _.filter(flights, function (value) {
    return value.airline !== 'all';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are methods from either [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) being used in those samples. They are not part of, nor require for Leaflet. The naming convention is one where I suppose searching for "_" would not be very fruitful if you weren't familiar with it already.

Comment: Thanks so much for that answer. I do see a a script tag above that includes underscore.js. I looked it over and see why it is being used! Thanks again for the help!